# How to query multiple ids in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid4

If I have a few IDs, say `[1,2,3]`

Is it possible to query them all at once in Mongoid? Such as:

`User.where({ id: [1,2,3]})` or something similar?

Answer (score 12):

The underlying MongoDB query you're looking for would use the [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

> The **$in** operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

In MongoDB, you'd say:

```
db.users.find({ id: { $in: [1,2,3] } })
```

That translates directly into Mongoid as:

```
User.where(id: { :$in => [1,2,3] })
```

Mongoid patches most (all?) of the query operators into `Symbol` so you'd usually say:

```
User.where(:id.in => [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 6):

Bit late to the party, but you can just pass an array of IDs to the find() method.

```
User.find(ids)
```

Comment: `User.find(ids)` will return a plain Ruby array. If you want to do batch DB operations with the result, for example, it's better to use `User.where(:id.in => [1,2,3])`.